# A subword in a word

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations, factorial

## Probability

So I have been trying to solve this question in probability, but I don't seem to get the correct answer. I am not bad at probability and this seems to be easy one, but I'm just struggling really bad on this one.
So the question is this:

> What's the probability of choosing $5$ letters from $a, b, g, d, e, z$ *(these are the first $6$ letters in Armenian alphabet)* so that the word "bad" will be included in it.
>   P.S. the letters cannot be repeated and "bad" can be anywhere in a $5$-letter word.

I know the answer, but I can't get it. I am trying to solve this in this way:
$$P = \frac{3!}{A(6, 5)}$$
$\color{blue}{A(n, k) = C(n, k) \cdot k!}$
Would be thankful if you could help me out.

`Here's the answer below for people wondering ↓`

> $P = \frac{1}{40}$

Comment: Is it so that the letters B A D will be in the choice of 5 letters, or the sequence of five letters has BAD in that specific order?  It's like saying does BGDAE == BADGE?

Comment: The meaning of the question is not clear to me, but never mind that. What I'd like to know is, what does $A(6,5)$ mean?

Comment: @bof I have seen this notation used before here but very infrequently.  It apparently denotes the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), $A(n,k)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n\cdot (n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$.  The notation seems to be intended to be analogous to the $C(n,k)$ notation for binomial coefficients.  That being said, @ DAVO, use whatever notation your teacher uses for the time being but once you get out of the course sequence you might want to swap to the more common notations.

Comment: As for the question itself, it is unclear whether you are allowed to repeat letters or not.  The attempt(?) (*answer?*) of $\frac{3!}{6!}$ doesn't seem correct in the most common interpretations of the problem.  Assuming the letters may not be repeated (*which would explain the $6!$ denominator*) assuming order of letters matters, and assuming `bad` can occur anywhere within the word and still count as having `bad` in it (*such as `gebad`*), I instead get a probability of $\frac{3\cdot 3\cdot 2}{6!}$.  The answer of $\frac{3\cdot 2}{6!}$ would make sense if `bad` had to appear at the start.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley "BAD" has to be in this order and it doesn't matter if this should be at the start of 5 letter word or at the end or middle. The 5 letter word should just contain it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yea $A(n, k)$ is that, true. And okay I will start. I just didn't know it's not universal :P Oh and no you can't repeat the letters. And yea the answer $\frac{3\cdot 3\cdot 2}{6!}$ is the right answer. But could explain why thoe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the probability of the event

$A$= you have the word "BAD" in the chosen letter combination

we need to evaluate

$$
P(A)=\frac{\text{A happened}}{\text{all possible outcomes}}.
$$

All possible outcomes are $\binom{6}{5}\cdot 5!=6\cdot 5!$ (You can think about this as we *remove* one letter and pick the rest hence the $6$ different options and we can arrange these in $5!$ different ways). To find the number of outcomes when we have the word "BAD" we will *glue* these letters together as one entity, let us refer to it as $\sigma$ from now on. This will of course always be chosen and then we have $3$ letters left to choose from and we need to fill $2$ empty places in the constructed word. You can choose the remaining two letters in $\binom{3}{2}$ different ways. Now we have $\sigma$ and $2$ more letters and these can be arranged in $3!$ different ways. So altogether we have
$$
\binom{3}{2}\cdot 3!
$$ 
different ways to construct a desired word.

Hope I could help.

Comment: _We have $3$ letters left to choose from_? 3 o 2? "BAD" is 3 letters hence we have 2 letters to choose to make up a 5-letter word, don't we? Or you mean to choose from 6 letters **(the small Alphabet)**? @Vinyl_coat_jawa

Comment: When you glue together "BAD" you have $3$ letters left from the original alphabet (it was without repetition). From these we need to choose $2$ to be able to construct a $5$ letter word since "BAD" takes up $3$ places.

Comment: Oh okay. I just thought you have to chose those $2$ letters from the $5$ letters that are being chosen, not from the original Alphabet. Thanks a lot for the help ;)

Comment: You are more than welcome!